# Java JPA query createQuery issue

Tags: java, servlets, jpa

I am learning JPA and have been following a tutorial.

The tutorial project is a simple "flight booking" dynamic site with JPA and derby database.

I have a Passenger class with @Entity annotation and a Passenger service class as a stateless local bean. Passenger service class has a getPassengers method which does "createQuery("SELECT p FROM PASSENGER p", Passenger.class);" and the returned result is a Passenger list.

To invoke this method I have a GetPassenger servlet and sets the query result list as a http request attribute and dispatches it to a jsp view file.

The problem is that when I run the servlet with the getPassengers method the returned list is empty even though I made sure there are several entries in the database's passenger table. Below are my codes. Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Passenger class:

```
package com.airline.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
* Entity implementation class for Entity: Passenger
*
*/
@Entity

public class Passenger implements Serializable {
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Passenger [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", dob=" + dob
            + ", gender=" + gender + ", flightclass=" + flightclass + "]";
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dob;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private FlightClass flightclass;
```

PassengerService class:

```
package com.airline.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import com.airline.models.Flight;
import com.airline.models.Passenger;

/**
*  Session Bean implementation class PassengerService
*/
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PassengerService {

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public PassengerService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "airline")
EntityManager em;

public void addPassenger(Passenger p) {
    em.persist(p);
}

public List<Passenger> getPassengers() {
    try{

    TypedQuery<Passenger> query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM PASSENGER p",    Passenger.class);

    List<Passenger> pList = (List<Passenger>)query.getResultList();

    return pList;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Passenger not found");
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

GetPassenger servlet:

```
package com.airline.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterState;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.airline.models.Flight;
import com.airline.models.Passenger;
import com.airline.service.FlightService;
import com.airline.service.PassengerService;

/**
* Servlet implementation class GetFlight
*/
@WebServlet("/GetPassenger")
public class GetPassenger extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@EJB
PassengerService ps;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public GetPassenger() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    List<Passenger> pList = (List<Passenger>)ps.getPassengers();

    request.setAttribute("Passenger_List", pList);

    if(pList == null)
    {
        System.out.println("passenger list empty");
        return;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/passenger_list.jsp");

    view.forward(request, response);


}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Comment: When I say the list is empty and I mean that on the console the try catch block under public List<Passenger> getPassengers() prints out "Passenger not found" and the servlet's if (pList==null) prints out passenger list empty.

Comment: also, these classes are a identical copy of the Flight, FlightService and GetFlight that I have made earlier which does exactly the same thing and prints out a list of the flights from the same database different table.

Comment: the only difference is that for the FlightService I used:      TypedQuery<Flight> fQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Flight.FindById", Flight.class); and @NamedQuery(name = "Flight.FindById", query = "SELECT f FROM Flight f WHERE f.id = :id") and the result is as expected a list of flights was printed out.

Comment: When you end up in the catch block and print "passenger list empty", what was the exception? This is likely your clue because you shouldn't get an exception even if there are no results. Debug into that block to see what the exception is, or do an e.printStackTrace()

Comment: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.payara-p1): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT p FROM PASSENGER p]. 
[14, 23] The abstract schema type 'PASSENGER' is unknown. --this is very strange. there is no schema under the database called PASSENGER, everything is under the schema "airline"...?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by changing the actual query from "SELECT p FROM PASSENGER p" to "SELECT p FROM Passenger p".

Passenger refers to the name of the entity class not the name of the table..?

Comment: Yes, JPA queries are against your Entity types and the properties on your entities, not directly against the tables and columns that they map to

Comment: "Passenger refers to the name of the entity class not the name of the table..?" - Yes.  JPQL is not SQL.

Comment: I realized this difference after some digging...thanks both for your time.